# Mouse cursor randomly jumps to screen edges

Tags: mouse, lenovo-laptop, manjaro

I have the problem that my mouse randomly jumps to the edges of the screen every minute. I use a Lenovo Yoga 7 with Manjaro (KDE Plasma; v5.27.8). I've already posted this question in the [Manjaro forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/mouse-cursor-randomly-jumps-to-screen-edges/149400?u=chraebsli) and [Lenovo forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Laptops/Mouse-cursor-randomly-jumps-to-screen-edges/m-p/5258710) but without a helpful answer.

The problem occurs both with touchpad enabled & disabled. It also occurs both with & without an external mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same laptop, installed archlinux, and immediately experienced this. After a few hours of monitoring libinput signals, I had enough suspicion that the Wacom pen input (not finger input) was causing the jump issue. I turned it off, and since then I'm no longer experiencing the jump issue.

This worked for me as,

1. I have no intention to use the stylus input (at least not while I'm on the linux side of the laptop).
2. I'm on xorg, and not sure if this is xorg only problem, nor how to apply the same "solution" to wayland sessions.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
... # some pointer input devices
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 5366 Finger                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]  # "touchscreen" input, I assume?
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 5366 Pen Pen (0)                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]  # this was causing the cursor to jump around
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
... # more devices as keyboards
    ↳ Wacom HID 5366 Pen                        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]  # button on the side of a wacom pen, I assume? I didn't touch this
... # then more

# set enabled=false
$ xinput set-prop "Wacom HID 5366 Pen Pen (0)" "Device Enabled" "0"

# confirm
$ xinput list-props "Wacom HID 5366 Pen Pen (0)" | grep "Device Enabled"
        Device Enabled (169):   0
```

NOTE: If you want to "permanently" disable it, you might want to set up a `xorg.conf` rule for that.